# UWP Cryptographic Interop ... Issues with Signatures

Tags: uwp, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I need to interop between Java/OSX/IOS/Windows.
I use the following:
  RSA/ECP/PKCS1 - 2048 bit key
  AES/CBC/PKCS7 - 256 bit key
  SHA512 for content hash and digital signatures

I have been using the OpenSSL libray during development and now wanting to move to standard C# libraries so I can release to the Windows APP store.
I have the following working locally and interoperating with the other platforms: SHA512 hash,  AES encrypt/decrypt,  RSA encrypt/decrypt.
What is left is Signature/Verification. This works locally but generates a different Signature then all the other platforms. So I am at a loss!

On other plaforms for Signing I Encrypt a SHA512 hash using the RSA Private Key.
On Windows UWP:
  Using the AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1 algorithm, you can NOT encrypt with the private key. The operation is not supported.
  Using the AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaSignPkcs1Sha512 algorithm, I am able to sign the Hash using:
        outData = CryptographicEngine.SignHashedData(mSignPrivateKey, inData);
  I am assuming that this call does not do any hashing, despite the algorithm name, since I already provided the hash in inData buffer. But this generates a different signature than the all the other platforms.

For testing I create a keypair in the OpenSSL library and obtained the encoded private key.
Then for Windows UWP I create the private key using the appropriate algorithm:
           mSignPrivateKey = sSignAlg.ImportKeyPair(encodedkey);
This strategy worked for testing the RSA Encrypt/Decrypt by using:
           mEncryptionPrivateKey = sRsaAlg.ImportKeyPair(encodedkey);

Any suggestions on where I may have gone wrong ?

Comment: Well I learned a little more ... If I decrypt the signature generated on UWP using RSA and the public key with OpenSSL ... I see that my hash is there ... but it has a 19 byte prefix.  So now I need to find out why ...

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, there's nothing that prevents you from using OpenSSL in an app in the windows store.

Comment: If I use the OpenSSL Library as built ... it fails the Application Verifier because it uses unsupported APIs. I could try to build a subset DLL and hope it does not drag in unneeded APIs.

Comment: I found out that the Standard Practice for Digital Signature is to add a header to the Hash before encryption that identifies the type of Hash algorithm used. Using my own procedures for generating Digital Signatures did not add this header ... and hence when I compared the ENTIRE unencrypted Signature with the HASH it failed. So my not following industry practices for generating a Digital signature caused the problem.

Comment: > If I use the OpenSSL Library as built ... it fails the Application Verifier because it uses unsupported APIs

You'll have to recompile it for UWP obviously (there's a fork that has done that here: https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_0_2_WinRT-stable).

Comment: @r.t.s. It seems like you've answered yourself in the comments, or are you still stuck somewhere? If you have an answer feel free to post it! Oh, yeah, you can also provide feedback on the crappy documentation of Mickeysoft, in case you want to know how it feels to get ignored.